# Google App Engine serve Content-Length header

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the following to serve a file from GS through PHP App Engine:

```
google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools::serve
```

This doesn't set the Content-Length header and App Engine doesn't allow that header to be set manually by a script. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled#headers_removed)

How can I set the Content-Length header so the user has an idea of how large the file is when they start to download it?

Answer (score 5):

I have experience with App Engine but used with Python, but I hope this is useful.

App Engine will remove the `Content-Length` header if you set it manually, but it will automatically set it before the response is sent to the client.

This ensures there are no mistakes on the value and it will be the length of the absolute final response sent by App Engine.

I have tested this with a new simple app by setting a wrong size manually, leaving it blank and setting the correct size. In all three tests, the correct `Content-Length` is returned to the client by App Engine.

Have you tested from the client to see if the header is present and correct?

I hope this helps clarify that while App Engine will remove the header if you set it, it will set it to the correct value automatically.

Comment: Thanks the reply.  I'm using PHP App Engine, the Content Length header is correct for every request, except when using google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools::serve. It is omitted.  Is this a bug with the PHP version?

Comment: I went on to read the specific documentation for the serve method. The signature reads serve(string $gs_filename, array<mixed,mixed> $options = array()). I can see that on the options you can provide start, end and use_range to change the served range of the file. Are you sending any options?

Comment: No, I'm only sending the filename

Comment: I discovered a HEAD request does return the proper Content-Length header, but omitted in a GET.

Comment: With such a specific behaviour I would file a bug report. Is this happening with all your files or just some files?

Comment: All files.  Do you know the proper place to report bugs?  I'm not able to find anything clear on their site.

Comment: This is the issue tracker where I report most issues: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list
If you pay for Silver or Gold support, even if just temporarily, you can report issues directly, even over the phone with Gold. And as I said, you can turn on support and then turn it off and only pay for the month where it was used.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the script provided by google [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) and run "[du](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du)" command you should be able to get that data. Also you have some interesting examples of the API's functionality [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples) and how install gsutil [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/).

Regards