# Content-length header not being set on Flask App Engine response for served blob

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

In my Flask-based Google App Engine server, I am trying to return a response with a 'content-length' header which will contain the final size of a blob being served to the client. This blob is a large media file, so this header is going to be used to set the maximum value of a progress bar on the UI frontend. The blob lives in Cloud Storage, but is using the blobstore API from the App Engine packages to retrieve the blob. Below returns with a `200` status code:

```
response.headers['Content-length'] = blobstore.BlobInfo(version.blob_key).size
return response
```

It is being received using the [Requests Python package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), and is streaming the data being received ([This should be fine, since all the headers are received in the `Response` object first before data streaming begins](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow)). My code looks something like below:

```
with requests.get(url='/api/download', stream=True) as r:
    print(r.headers)
```

However, there is no `Content-length` header being set. Instead, I get something like this from the `print()` above:

```
{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 
 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 
 'X-Cloud-Trace-Context': '1bca54f9cdae7394de6cb2f1e824ba6f', 
 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
 'Date': 'Thu, 26 Apr 2018 11:36:17 GMT',
 'Server': 'Google Frontend'}
```

I noticed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087505/google-app-engine-serve-content-length-header) that App Engine strips the content-length header and replaces it with the correct size, but I'm not getting a content-length header to begin with. What am I doing incorrectly? Am I serving the blob to the client wrong? Is the content-length simply unavailable and cannot be set? If so, how can I retrieve the size of the file so I can compute the size of my UI progress bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Content-Length` header is included in the [list of headers that can't be modified](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-requests#request_headers).

As you and the documentation pointed out, App Engine calculates the Content-Length header from the request data and adds it to the request prior to sending.

You can always set a personalized header, Flask allows it, and GAE will let you use it.

For example, for your response:

```
response.headers['CL-blob'] = blobstore.BlobInfo(version.blob_key).size
```