# Microsoft AD App validation failed: "microsoft-identity-association.json has a content length that is not set or otherwise invalid"

Tags: http, google-app-engine, flask, azure-active-directory

I am struggling to validate our app with Azure Active Directory, to use their SSO.

To validate our domain, they ask to make a JSON file available at this address: `{publisher_domain}/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json`

In our Flask app, I'm serving the file using this route:

```py
@app.route('/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json')
def microsoft_identity_association():
    file = '.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json'

    return send_file(file, mimetype='application/json')
```

I also tried to load the JSON into a dictionary and return the dictionary letting Flask rendering the response:

```py
@app.route('/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json')
def microsoft_identity_association():
    file = '.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json'
    with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        result = ujson.load(file)
        response = flask.Response(result, mimetype='application/json')
        response.headers.add('content-length' , str(result.__len__()))

    return send_file(file, mimetype='application/json')
```

But every time, I get the same result:

In the response to a GET request, the `content-length` header is present in my local environment but disappear when my app is deployed on Google App Engine Flex.
I checked their documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/request-headers) and contacted them but with no real success.
They say " it seems like this is working as intended. HTTP/2 doesn't require "content-length" and thus it's stripped away."

It looks like this procedure for Microsoft app validation is new (may 2019), so hard to find similar problems.

Has someone here faced the same situation and hopefully found a solution?

Comment: I think your inquiry is answered in this thread [1].
[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042455/content-length-header-not-being-set-on-flask-app-engine-response-for-served-blob

Comment: Thank you for the link. It's linked to Google App Engine Standard, thought. The list of altered headers is not the same for Google App Engine Flex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After more research and some time spent between different technical supports, I finally found a solution to validate our app. I'll explain it here in case it could be useful to someone.

## Cause of the issue

The validation process proposed by Microsoft Azure AD was emitting a GET request to an endpoint on our server and expecting an 'aplication/json' response with the proper 'content-lenght' header.

But our server is using the HTTP 1.1 protocol and

> For version 1.1 of the HTTP protocol, the chunked transfer mechanism
> is considered to be always acceptable, even if not listed in the TE
> request header field, and when used with other transfer mechanisms,
> should always be applied last to the transferred data and never more
> than one time. (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding))

And

> A sender MUST NOT send a Content-Length header field in any message
> that contains a Transfer-Encoding header field.
> (Source: [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2))

It appears that the verification process does not complies with the HTTP 1.1 protocol.

## Solution

The solution is finally quite simple: **use an alternative domain validation procedure**

On Azure AD, I was able to valide our domain using a TXT record on our DN, as described in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain#add-your-custom-domain-name-to-azure-ad)

I hope this will help other people stuck with app domain validation.

Answer (score 0):

For the Flexible environment, these are the relevant documentation [1][2], also according to this documentation [3], a sender MUST NOT send a Content-Length header field in any message that contains a Transfer-Encoding header field.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/request-headers

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled

[3] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2

Comment: Thank you for the links to the doc. My app is not sending any Transfer-Encoding header.